# Integration Simplification

Tags: integration

Is there a simple way to express

$$\int_0^a f(x)^2\,\mathrm{d}x$$
in terms of $$\int_0^a f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x,$$ 
$f(0)$, $f(a)$ and $a$, which are all known entities?

Comment: Without more information, the best you can get is an inequality by Cauchy-Schwarz. Unless I missed something.

Comment: Think to $f(x)=1/(x+a)$, for instance, or $f(x)$ any polynomial.

Answer (score 1):

No. Let $a=2\pi, f_1(x)=0, f_2(x)=\sin(x)$. Then the first value $\int_0^a f(x)^2$ will be different for $f=f_1$ and $f=f_2$, but the latter four "known entities" will be the same for $f_1$ and $f_2$. Thus if you only know the latter four, you cannot determine what the first value is.

Answer (score 1):

Let $f(x)=xe^{-x^2/2}$. Tnen $\int_0^a f(x)\,dx$ is easily found.

But now consider $\int_0^a f^2(x)\,dx$.  By integrating by parts, we can show that 
$$\int_0^a x^2e^{-x^2}\,dx= -\frac{1}{2}ae^{-a^2}+\frac{1}{2}\int_0^a e^{-x^2}\,dx.$$
It is known that the integral on the right cannot be expressed in terms of elementary functions of $a$, so neither can $\int_0^a f^2(x)\,dx$.